# CMake 3.22.4 does not compatible with GTest 1.10.0.20201025-1.1

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, googletest

I've build my unit test code on Ubuntu 21.10, CMake 3.18.4 and GTest 1.10.0.20201025-1.1.
I wrote CMakeList.txt file as this.

```
# The minimum version of CMake Required
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.12)

# Any project name will suffice, this has connotaions when using advanced CMake Features
set(PROJECT_NAME tests)
project (${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

# Just in case someone had the include files in seperate directory
include_directories(../include)
include_directories(..)

# This uses the complete student's library
aux_source_directory(.. SRC_LIST)
list(REMOVE_ITEM SRC_LIST "../main.cpp")
message ( STATUS "Compiling test_lib with following files  ${SRC_LIST}" )
add_library(test_lib ${SRC_LIST})

# Now we make the gtests

set(GTEST_ROOT "/usr/src/gtest" CACHE PATH "Path to googletest")
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

if(NOT GTEST_LIBRARY)
   message("GTest library not found")
endif()

add_executable(rawTests test_rawdata.cpp)
target_link_libraries(rawTests ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread)
target_link_libraries(rawTests test_lib)

add_executable(timeTests test_time.cpp)
target_link_libraries(timeTests ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread)
target_link_libraries(timeTests test_lib)
```

It works properly on my end.

But when I deliver this to my friend who uses CMake 3.22.4, it throws error look like this

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1Auz.png)

It's kind of weird issue and I didn't ever faced this sort of issue before.

I wonder anybody who has deep knowledge for CMake and GTest can help me to handle this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can not find != is not compatible.

Comment: It seems your friend forgot to install GTest, or have installed it into location other than `/usr/src/gtest`, as assigned to `GTEST_ROOT` variable. Note also, that on Stack Overflow we expect the **error message** to be in the question post itself, as **text**, not linked as *image*.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Thank you for your comment. I've checked that GTest has been correctly installed to my friend's machine.

Comment: And what about the **path** to GTest installation, it it `/usr/src/gtest` or some other? Please, add **details** about your problem into the **question post**. And please, paste the **text** of the error into the question post. As I said in my previous comment, an image is not a proper way to show that message. See also [ask].